# Error In Haskell Platform 2010.2.0.0 Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform

I have got an error during command execution "cabal update" on Haskell Platform 2010.2.0.0. Error message is "cabal: Codec.Compression.Zlib: incorrect header check". OS version is Windows XP SP3, Cabal version is 0.8.2. Cabal library version is 1.8.0.2. All are from default package. Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: 2John: did you mean "cabal upgrade"?

Comment: @Yuras, yes, that's the one.  Cabal update is necessary and should be harmless.  Deleting my earlier comment since it's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You might find it is the problem in [this ticket](https://web.archive.org/web/20130416082447/http://hackage.haskell.org:80/trac/hackage/ticket/686). We think the problem is with misconfigured HTTP proxies that lie about doing transparent decompression. We think we have a fix, so you could try using the latest darcs version of cabal-install and see if that works for you. Either way, add your experience to the ticket so we can either confirm the fix or work out why it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Cabal library 1.10 or later and cabal-install from darcs HEAD already have a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in haskell-cafe (can't provide a link at a moment), you can

- Try with upgrade `HTTP` library or
- Try `wget http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/00-index.tar.gz` and place the tarball to the `~/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org`